# PowerShell script failling on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

Currently we got an C# MVC web application with basic Windows Authentication deployed on IIS 7.5 on Win Server 2012 R2.

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "ID,cmd,arg1,arg2")] PowerShellCMD PScmd)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           //String script = @"C:\TEMP\test.ps1";
            String script = @"D:\a-espinoza\Scripts\wsa.ps1";

            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            ps.Runspace = runspace;

            ps.Runspace.Open();

            using (var impersonationContext = ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Impersonate())
            {

                ps.AddScript(script);
                ps.AddParameter(null, PScmd.cmd);

                // Execute the script
                var results = ps.Invoke();

                runspace.Close();

                if (results.Count > 0)
                {
                    // We use a string builder ton create our result text
                    var builder = new StringBuilder();

                    foreach (var psObject in results)
                    {
                        // Convert the Base Object to a string and append it to the string builder.
                        // Add \r\n for line breaks
                        builder.Append(psObject + "\r\n");
                    }

                    // Encode the string in HTML (prevent security issue with 'dangerous' caracters like < >
                    PScmd.result = Server.HtmlEncode(builder.ToString());
                }
            }
            //impersonationContext.Undo();
        }

        return View(PScmd);
    }
```

Wherever an user without login rights on the IIS server where my app is deployed got the bellow error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not
>   allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the
>   required permission please contact your system administrator or change
>   the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Requested
>   registry access is not allowed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.]
>   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable)
>   +14302727    System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(String variable, EnvironmentVariableTarget target) +278
>   System.Management.Automation.ModuleIntrinsics.GetExpandedEnvironmentVariable(String
>   name, EnvironmentVariableTarget target) +9
>   System.Management.Automation.ModuleIntrinsics.SetModulePath() +61
>   System.Management.Automation.ExecutionContext.InitializeCommon(AutomationEngine
>   engine, PSHost hostInterface) +714
>   System.Management.Automation.AutomationEngine..ctor(PSHost
>   hostInterface, RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration,
>   InitialSessionState iss) +19187352
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace.DoOpenHelper()
>   +19188647    System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.CoreOpen(Boolean
>   syncCall) +360
>   PowerShellExecution.Controllers.PWCmdsController.Index(PowerShellCMD
>   PScmd) +254    lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>   +127    System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +242
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +12
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +139
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
>   +112    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
>   +452    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
>   +37    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +241
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +111
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +19
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +111
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +606    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34274

How can we avoid the error without allow everyone access on the server running IIS?

The Register key have already given read access to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to look at the Security logs on the server to see which user is causing the SecurityException?

I could be a little off on this one...but the Runspace is being created outside of the Impersonation so it would be running as the Application Pool identity/user.  I wouldn't expect that to run when any user accesses the site.

The user you're impersonating will have to have access to the registry key your script is referencing.  Check this out to accomplish that: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775454(v=ws.10).aspx

Try changing:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
ps.Runspace = runspace;
ps.Runspace.Open();

using (var impersonationContext = ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Impersonate())
{
    //...Code
}
```

To:

```
using (var impersonationContext = ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Impersonate())
{
    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    ps.Runspace = runspace;
    ps.Runspace.Open();

    //...Code
}
```

Comment: After do your suggested update on the code I can verify that impersonation is working, as Event logs confirm the user (impersonated) entry. But still same error, its like user don't have access to read the registry, if I execute the script with that user logged to the server it works